# Spring Security Oauth2: Fallback when access token is invalid/expired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security to protect my endpoints.

My problem is, is it possible to response differently when users are using valid/invalid access token?

For example, for a single /api/info

(1) When an invalid/expired access token is passed in the request, only very limited information will be returned 
(2) When a valid access token is passed in the request, very customized and rich content is returned according to a different user.

I've tried to use `access=permitAll()`, but it doesn't work because invalid tokens can not pass oauth2 validation.

Using `security="none"` is also not working because it will not try to get user info at all.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom [OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/error/OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler.html) and plug it to your `/info` endpoint using `security:access-denied-handler` XML tag or Similar Java Config.

Comment: Thank you! I forget to say there are about 20 endpoints api having similar needs. Is there a way to reuse the same code when dealing valid/invalid access tokens? the code is expected to be like `if (currentUser != null){ model.write(currentUser.getInfo(xxx) ) ;} `

Comment: One access Denied Handler can be used for multiple endpoints.